# Xamarin iOS: Can we set stoardboardid in XIB file?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard, xib

I want to pop couple of viewcontrollers from a navigation stack. Ex: If a navigation set has a,b,c,d,e I want to jump from e to b or e to c. For this I am planning to use navigationcontroller.Popviewcontroller(strybrdId,Animatn). When I was looking at XIB files, they do not have option to set storyboardID. Is their any way to set storyboardID or any better way to pop views ?

Comment: Where is that method `PopViewController(storyboardId, animated)` coming from? I don't see that on `UINavigationController`. You should be able to use `PopToViewController(UIViewController, bool animated)` to do what you want if you can get a reference to view controller, which will be in the navigation controller's `ViewControllers` property.

Comment: Check your UIViewcontroller existence in the stack, if it is there then pop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
var controllers = this.NavigationController.ViewControllers;
int index = 0;
while (controllers[index].GetType() != typeof(ViewControllerYouWantToPopTo))
{
    index++;
}
this.NavigationController.PopToViewController(controllers[index], true);
```